# How to change cmd start directory for administrator level by GPO

Tags: group-policy

I need to change the start directory of elevated command prompt for the whole domain. I can't find any setting in GPO, which would do that. Anyone knows, where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a registry key (reg_sz) named "Autorun" under:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\

Put a "CD C:\" in there and it will start in C:\

More can be found on [MS Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb490880.aspx)